# Concurrency Loop in python

Tags: python-3.x, concurrency, python-asyncio, event-loop

My Scenario:- Start, Wait, Start, Stop or Kill

1. Starting the first event & waiting for some time.
2. If I reach the waiting time, I need to start the second event & return both event result.
3. But, if the first event completed before waiting time.
4. No need to start the second event.
5. Return the first event result

Ex:-

```
import asyncio

async def some_task():
    print('io start')
    await asyncio.sleep(2)
    print('io end')
    return "hello"

async def callback(loop):
    await asyncio.sleep(4)
    if loop.is_running():
        print('doing other things')

if __name__ == "__main__":
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    loop2 = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    a = loop.create_task(some_task())
    b = loop2.create_task(callback(loop))
    result = loop.run_until_complete(a)
    loop2.run_until_complete(b)
    loop.close()
    loop2.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

The variables `loop` and `loop2` will get the same (main) event loop, which is why it will always still be running. Here is my approach:

```py
import asyncio

async def async_main():
    result = None

    async def some_task():
        print('io start')
        await asyncio.sleep(6)
        print('io end')
        result = "hello"
        return result

    async def callback():
        await asyncio.sleep(4)
        if result is None:
            print('doing other things')

    awaited = await asyncio.gather(
        asyncio.create_task(some_task()),
        asyncio.create_task(callback()),
    )
    return awaited

asyncio.run(async_main())
```

Asyncio can be very confusing and I do not recommend it for non-experts, so here is an alternative using `threading` instead of `asyncio`:

```py
import threading
import time

def do_tasks():
    result = None

    def some_task():
        nonlocal result
        print('io start')
        time.sleep(2)
        print('io end')
        result = "hello"

    def callback():
        time.sleep(4)
        if result is None:
            print('doing other things')

    threading.Thread(target=some_task).start()
    threading.Thread(target=callback).start()

do_tasks()
```